# How to get the value by key and another value with linq? vbnet

Tags: c#, linq

```
Public ets As New Dictionary(Of String, info)

Public Class info

    Public Property index As Integer

    Public Property imglst_index As Integer

End Class
```

i want to get   imglst_index by index="x"and key="y" in dictionary with linq query.

```
     For Each subKey As String In subKeys

             Dim result = exts.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Key = subkey AndAlso x.Value.ext_icon_index = subkey.DefaultIcon.Index).Value.ext_imglst_index

                  if result>0 then item2.imageindex=result

                    Dim item As New ListViewItem(subKey)
                    item.ImageIndex = ImageList.Images.Count - 1
                    item.Tag = subKey
                    Items.Add(item)
                    exts.Add(subkey, New ext_info With {.ext_icon_index = subkey.DefaultIcon.Index, .ext_imglst_index = item.ImageIndex})


     Next subKey
```

here my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it..

```
Dim result = ets.First(Function(x) x.Key = "y" AndAlso x.Value.index="x") _
                .Value _
                .imglst_index
```

Comment: Exception:Caught: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (System.NullReferenceException) getting this error. after returning two results

Comment: added in first post

Comment: @ErolCimen you might need split that line of code in multiple statements to check for nulls. For example, first statement will only have FirstOrDefault. You will do null check for result and access `Value` property only if the result is no null. Same applies to imglst_index property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim infos As New List(Of info)
        ets = infos.GroupBy(Function(x) x.index).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.FirstOrDefault())
    End Sub
    Public ets As New Dictionary(Of Integer, info)

    Public Class info

        Public Property index As Integer

        Public Property imglst_index As Integer

    End Class

End Module
```